# How to deploy Angular 6 prod build artifacts and python code on a single server

Tags: python, angular, flask

I have a Angular 6 code base, from here am building angular 6 code for production and generating production ready artifact. 
I have python back-end code running on a server. I want to deploy this production ready angular 6 artifacts to same python server. I am using python with flask.

I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can using **ng build** to build an artifacts folder for production. And the copy that under your python server main folder.

Comment: Are you referring to root folder of python code as main?

Comment: There should be a folder named **static**, also you can change that .
http://devarea.com/building-a-simple-website-with-angular-4-and-django-and-deploy-it-to-heroku/#.W3_EwegzaUk